# Context-Sensitive Grammar characteristic properties

Tags: fl.formal-languages, grammars, context-free

This question can look like some kind of puzzle, but it is actually part of more complex applied problem.

Let's consider subspace of Context-Sensitive Grammars, which contains grammars which can not be represented neither as Context-Free Grammars, neither as Regular Grammars. Let's call them "*strong* CSG".

And let's suppose that we are given only by alphabet, set of nonterminals, set of production rules, but **without left sides** (which is hidden from us). For instance:

$\Sigma=\{a,b,c\}$
$N=\{S,B,W,X\}$

and rules:

1. $?\rightarrow abc$
2. $?\rightarrow aSBc$
3. $?\rightarrow WB$
4. $?\rightarrow WX$
5. $?\rightarrow BX$
6. $?\rightarrow Bc$
7. $?\rightarrow bb$

**The question is**: are any general properties regarding right-side of these production rules using which we can distinguish *strong*-CSG from CFG and RG looking only on this non-complete set of rules?

***Alternative formulation of this question***: in this particular case, can given grammar be Context-free?

Let's also consider that in case of CFG given grammar is always present in [reduced](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995870800079) (simplified) form (by reduction I mean finding a CFG with the fewest nonterminal symbols or with the fewest rules that is equivalent to G) - (we're talking here about weak-equivalent grammar with smallest number of non-terminals and production rules - thanks to @Marzio De Biasi for pointing this).

*Disclaimer*: original grammar was Context-Sensitive, taken from wikipedia article.

Comment: Can you give a formal definition of "*reduced (simplified) form*" for a Context Sensitive Grammar  (or a reference)? I made a quick search but didn't find an exact definition and the only "normal form" I remember for CSGs is Kuroda normal form.

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi Thank you, that's good point. It actually was confusing statement. I meant that in case when given grammar is CF, then it is in reduced form. I've updated my question to make it more clear.

Comment: But even for CFGs  "*reduced (simplified) form*" seems not a standard/frequently-used term (but I'm not an expert) and you should clarify what it means. Do you mean "Chomsky normal form" (or equivalently "Chomsky reduced form")? Obviously, in that case, the ?->aSBc, ?->abc, ?->Bc, ?->bb rules imply that the given grammar is not CF (assuming that if it is CF then it is given in Chomsky normal form)

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi by reduction I mean finding a CFG with the fewest nonterminal symbols or with the fewest rules that is equivalent to G, see for instance http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995870800079

Comment: Ok, thanks; I gave a quick look at the paper and there are two notions: "weakly equivalent" and "structural equivalence"; the first seems undecidable; so your problem can potentially be undecidable; indeed if the left side can be "filled" to get a valid CFG $G$ (e.g. for your example X->abc, S->aSBc, S->WB, W->WX, W->BX, B->Bc, B->bb), then we should check that there is not a smaller (reduced) grammar $G'$ which is weakly equivalent to $G$ (if there is one, then $G$ violates the "promise"); but this is undecidable.

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi thanks for your exploration, this could be an accepted answer, as you provided good conterexample.

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi Please look at my commentary under your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47127/discussion-between-marzio-de-biasi-and-andremoniy).